# How to insert concatenated values into single column?

Tags: php

i am writing an application that queries data from different tables and concatenates them together before it inserts them into angle          table.I am running into a few challenges,and will need some help.Below is some of my code:

```
       $sql="select employees.id as  id,message_dispensary,message_surgery,message_biochemistry,heading 
               from messages
              join supervisors
                  using(employee_id)
               join employees
              on (employees.id=supervisors.employee_id)";   
             $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die ("error in retrieving results.".mysqli_error($link));  
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='message[]' value=".$row['heading'].'&nbsp;'.$row['message_surgery'].'&nbsp;'.$row  ['message_biochemistry'].'&nbsp;'";?>
       "</td></tr>";
    }
        ?>
       <tr><td><input type="submit"> </form> </table>
```

my problem is how to get "ALL" the values i am placing in the input box named "messages"...the values keep truncating, and some rows do not have some of the values. Please show me where i am missing it or even a more elegant solution.Thanks....

Comment: Have you tried with phpmyadmin ? Perhaps you should use htmlspecialchars on the field values if you suspect that something is being hidden when rendered as HTML. Also view the page source.

Comment: i need it as a script cos i need to write it for users to insert stuff into the database

Comment: it gets truncated when i insert it into the table..

Comment: yep that happens if the string is longer than the column length, although MySQL issues a warning which you can see with SHOW WARNINGS. You can use the CONCAT function CONCAT(heading,'&nbsp;',message_surgery,'&nbsp;',message_biochemistry) AS single_col_message .

Comment: Ok thanks george...i will try that

Answer (score 0):

You could try `<textarea>` instead of `<input type='text'>`, whose length and width you can control by the `cols` and `rows` attributes:

```
echo "<textarea name='messages[]' cols='10' rows='10'>{$row['message_surgery']}</textarea>" ;
```

You can even have multiple textareas, one for each message type. If you are going to edit the database data and save it back in the database you will need to do this in any case.

Comment: Ok fanis....i will do that..but i will need them to be concatenated together cos they need to be in a single column

Comment: I tried the textarea...but none of the values i selected are showing as values...ie the '$row['heading']'

Comment: and how can i concatenate the values?